# How to troubleshoot entity error

Tags: views, 8, composer

How can I tell which entity is throwing this error (on all pages)?

> TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Block::__construct() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface, instance of Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager given, called in /usr/local/var/www/hifldlive/web/modules/contrib/ctools/modules/ctools_views/src/Plugin/Display/Block.php on line 54 in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Block->__construct() (line 69 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/display/Block.php).

I have run composer update on an un-familiar site.
Composer update, `drush updb` and `drush cr` all run without errors.
There are about 20 migration tables generated.

I'm guessing I need to roll back the composer update (since it trashes the site), fix the data, then re-run the composer update.
I stuck on how to identify what to fix.
It is no problem to roll back.

I can't where entities are stored in the database. 
I also don't see entities in the admin pages.

I can use Drupal Entity API in a custom module, but the site won't load on any page.

Comment: This is not a problem with entities stored in the database. You have outdated core/module code, either core or ctools is much older than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with entities stored in the database, it is is a version conflict between the module Ctools and Drupal core.

When you install the current version of Ctools with `composer require 'drupal/ctools:^3.4'` you see that __construct() is calling the parent constructor providing a parameter EntityTypeManagerInterface.

*modules/contrib/ctools/modules/ctools_views/src/Plugin/Display/Block.php*

```
  /**
   * Constructs a new Block instance.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockManagerInterface $block_manager
   *   The block manager.
   * @param \Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager $filter_manager
   *   The views filter plugin manager.
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The current request.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, BlockManagerInterface $block_manager, ViewsHandlerManager $filter_manager, Request $request) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $entity_type_manager, $block_manager);

    $this->filterManager = $filter_manager;
    $this->request = $request;
  }
```

This requires that your core version has this code change:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/commit/12d7ed53087a469ef8f87476c2849f7b24bfbbb7#140e79af0797f7f25fd1f20e2ebc697be118fea6

So you have to make sure you are using a current core version 8.8.x or you have to downgrade Ctools to a version not having this change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exact answer.  Changed composer.json to         "drupal/ctools": "3.2",  without the ^, ran composer update, and all is well.